# Europe import gets stuck on ways

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap

A full import of https://download.geofabrik.de/europe-latest.osm.pbf gets stuck as soon as it gets to ways.

```
Processing: Node(2605985k 456.3k/s) Way(638k 0.18k/s) Relation(0 0.0/s)
```

I have tried it with both v1.20 of osm2pgsql that comes with Nominatim v3.5.1 and also osm2pgsql 1.3.0 which is the most up to date version.

I'm running the import on a 96core machine with 50GB of RAM and 750GB SSD. It has worked previously very quickly for other regions. My `--osm2pgsql-cache` is set to 25000 which is enough to hold the entire pbf file in memory.

My postgres.conf is:

```
# Defaults from postgres db init
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  # the default is the first option
min_wal_size = 80MB
log_timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
lc_messages = 'C.UTF-8'         # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'C.UTF-8'         # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'C.UTF-8'          # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'C.UTF-8'             # locale for time formatting

# Based on https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostgreSQL
shared_buffers = 4GB
maintenance_work_mem = 10GB
autovacuum_work_mem = 1GB
work_mem = 256MB
checkpoint_timeout = 10min
max_wal_size = 25GB
```

Output of top as well:

```
top - 03:21:56 up  7:36,  0 users,  load average: 1.10, 1.09, 1.04
Tasks:  19 total,   1 running,  18 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  87092.1 total,  30475.4 free,  27253.4 used,  29363.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.  54874.0 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                              
     38 postgres  20   0 4404008   4.1g   4.1g S   1.7   4.8   1:30.25 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
    169 postgres  20   0 4392784   4.1g   4.1g D   1.3   4.8   4:41.63 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
    165 nominat+  20   0   27.2g  24.7g  11836 S   1.0  29.1  31:39.34 osm2pgsql                                                                                                                                                                                            
     39 postgres  20   0 4391716   4.0g   4.0g S   0.3   4.7   0:23.79 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
      1 root      20   0    8700   3572   3276 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 init.sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
     36 postgres  20   0 4391580 127672 125776 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.97 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
     40 postgres  20   0 4391580  21996  20080 S   0.0   0.0   1:31.52 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
     41 postgres  20   0 4392120   8544   6328 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.33 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
     42 postgres  20   0   71768   4808   2912 S   0.0   0.0   0:13.07 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
     43 postgres  20   0 4392004   6920   4828 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
     62 nominat+  20   0   78824  25384  19972 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 setup.php                                                                                                                                                                                            
     67 postgres  20   0 4410852  36408  32900 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
    164 nominat+  20   0    2612    608    540 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    168 postgres  20   0 4410044   4.1g   4.1g S   0.0   4.8  62:42.30 postgres                                                                                                                                                                                             
    171 postgres  20   0 4427500   1.9g   1.9g S   0.0   2.3   4:04.50 postgres
```

Comment: Offtopic, not a programming question. Try https://help.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: help.openstreetmap.org is pretty much dead by now, and may vanish completely soon.

osm2pgsql developers are active on the tile-serving mailing list, either ask there, or try a bug report on the osm2pgsql github project.

https://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/tile-serving